# c# example for simple WPD/PTP/MTP image aquisition

Tags: c#, wpd

I want to build a super simple software which just downloads an image from a digital camera when it is taken (tethering).

As far as I understand I can use Windows Portable Devices (WPD) with the picture/media transfer protocol (PTP/MTP) to aquire the images.

I found examples how to get started with WPD here:

- https://github.com/geersch/WPD

There are just a few more questions:

- WPD even enumerates external hdds - how do I know if a device is a camera?
- How do I get notified if another camera is connected?
- How can I get notified when the camera takes a picture?

Comment: Google led me here. All your links are dead.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp -  https://web.archive.org/web/20150517055001/http://cgeers.com:80/2011/05/22/enumerating-windows-portable-devices, https://web.archive.org/web/20150313012654/http://cgeers.com:80/2011/06/05/wpd-enumerating-content/, https://web.archive.org/web/20150316200913/http://cgeers.com/2011/08/13/wpd-transferring-content/